# PHP Insert multiple PDF's into PDF on specific page number

Tags: php, cakephp, pdf, merge, page-numbering

My problem is - A user can upload a PDF-File and now I want to add other (between 1 and n) single page PDF's after every Page of the user uploaded PDF.

For example a user uploads a PDF with 4 Pages and I have got 3 single page PDF's on my Webserver that I want to merge with the user PDF. The resulting PDF should then look like this:

> Page 1: Page #1 from User uploaded PDF
>
> Page 2: First Single-Page-PDF from Webserver
>
> Page 3: Page #2 from User uploaded PDF
>
> Page 4: Second Single-Page-PDF from Webserver
>
> Page 5: Page #3 from User uploaded PDF
>
> Page 6: Third Single-Page-PDF from Webserver
>
> Page 7: Page #4 from User uploaded PDF
>
> Page 8: First Single-Page-PDF from Webserver

So far I've tried it with **PDFMerger**

```
$pdf = new PDFMerger;

$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/userpdf.pdf', 'all')
    ->addPDF('samplepdfs/one.pdf', 'all')
    ->addPDF('samplepdfs/two.pdf', 'all')
    ->addPDF('samplepdfs/three.pdf', 'all')
    ->merge('file', 'xxx/result.pdf');
```

but this only adds the other PDF's at the end..
Is there a solution in PHP where I can specify the number of the page where the other PDF's shall be inserted?

Comment: what is the resuting page order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using the PDFMerger class. It is almost 6 (!!!) years old!
You can do the same with FPDI without much effort. Anyhow you should insert the pages in the order you want them to appear. So I guess it's more a logic problem. From what you'd written in your question I assume that you want to import a whole document while spreading another document with 3 pages between the imported pages. So a simple POC could look like this:

```
<?php

require_once("libs/fpdf/fpdf.php");
require_once("libs/fpdi/fpdi.php");

$pdf = new FPDI();

// let's prepare the static "filler pages"
$staticIds = array();
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('pdf/on/the/webserver.pdf');
for ($pageNumber = 1; $pageNumber <= $pageCount; $pageNumber++) {
    $staticIds[$pageNumber] = $pdf->importPage($pageNumber);
}

// get the page count of the uploaded file
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('the/uploaded.pdf');
// let's track the page number for the filler page
$fillerPageCount = 1;
// import the uploaded document page by page
for ($pageNumber = 1; $pageNumber <= $pageCount; $pageNumber++) {
    $tplId = $pdf->importPage($pageNumber);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplId, null, null, 0, 0, true);

    // add the current filler page
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($staticIds[$fillerPageCount], null, null, 0, 0, true);

    // update the filler page number or reset it
    $fillerPageCount++;
    if ($fillerPageCount > count($staticIds)) {
        $fillerPageCount = 1;
    }
}

// done
$pdf->Output('xxx/result.pdf', 'F');
```

Comment: I'm using mPdf to get something similar to this. In my case I have a PDF with page numbering in it. Now somebody comes with two new pdfs and asks me to merge these two new pdf in my pdf at some certain page. Say at position 3 and position 7. Also by the end the  page number should now be arranged accordingly. Any suggestion how that can be done?

Comment: @DeepakSingh That's simply a logic problem and should be solved by you as the programmer.